# Java Visual Studio-like menubar

Tags: java, swing, visual-studio, menu

How can I decorate a Swing `Menu` to look like the ones in `Visual Studio`. Here's a picture :

Visual studio's menu:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QsAf.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

You can use menu, for detail follow this  [Java Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) .

Also look at [Changing Look and Feel of Menu](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html).